# Why is this function not $C^2$?

Tags: functions, partial-derivative

Disclaimer: This is a question from a book on functions of several variables. The answer is in the back of the book.

---

I have a function

$f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{xy(x^2 - y^2)}{x^2 + y^2} &\text{for}\ (x,y) \not= (0,0) \\
0 &\text{for}\ (x, y) = (0, 0)
\end{cases}$

I have shown that it is continuous, by converting to polar coordinates and shown that

$\lim_{(r, \theta) \rightarrow (0, 0)} = 0$

I have also done the partial derivative and they too are continuous, so the function is $C^1$.

Using

\begin{align}
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\frac{\partial f}{ \partial y}(h, 0) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0, 0)}{h} = 1
\end{align}

So we can see that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}(0, 0) = 1$ and likewise we see that $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x}(0, 0) = -1$.

My question is now: How do we prove that the function is not $C^2$? The answer at the back of the book just states that it is not, however as far as the definition of $C^2$ goes we just have to prove that the mixed derivatives exists and are continuous, which I believe that they are? What am I missing? I get that they are not the same, and that a $C^2$-function have equal mixed derivatives, however the converse isn't true.

Comment: The converse is not interesting here; what you want to use is the contrapositive: "P implies Q" is the same thing as "not Q implies not P". With P = "$f$ is $C^2$" and Q = "$f_{xy}=f_{yx}$" here, of course.

Comment: That is so true. I had forgotten about proofs with contraposition! It been way too long since I had a course on proof at University. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome!